# Проблема в ПХП с кодировкой и функцией substr

Tags: php, html, кодировка

Всем доброго времени суток.Изучаю пхп,на данный момент столкнулся с функцией

> substr возвращает подстроку строки

```
$string_count = "Дана строка:Maxim<br>";
echo $string_count;
echo substr($string_count,1,3);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но выводит какие то символы,в чем может быть проблема?
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: вкратце: 1 латинский символ - 1 байт,  
1 символ кириллицы - 2 байта

Comment: Благодарю.
Как я понял
substr() идет переполнение если кириллица.
а что такое mb?
или эт нужно углубляться в php?

Comment: с `mb_` начинаются функции для работы с Многобайтными строками http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция `substr()` работает с однобайтовой кодировкой и возвращает не три символа из строки, а три байта, при этом, могу предположить, что файл у Вас сохранен в кодировки UTF-8, то есть многобайтовой.

Следовательно, Вы получаете три байта из строки в кодировке UTF-8, которые выглядят так, как Вы видите. Для того, чтобы получить желаемый результат проще всего использовать функции для работы с многобайтовыми кодировками. В Вашем случае это [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: Благодарю,над еще и в сторону кодировки покапать)

Answer (score 2):

Открываем гугл и пишем

> php substr русские символы

И всё сразу же становится на свои места.

Используйте

```
mb_substr($string_count,1,3);
```

Comment: Окей.Благодарю)

Comment: К сожалению тут только можно выбрать 1 ответ,человек сверху дал более развернутый,простите :D